# Issue converting NTEXT & nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

How can I convert an NTEXT column to NVARCHAR(MAX)?

I have 4 databases in which there is a table that exists in all four. Inside of this table there exists a `Notes` column of type `NTEXT` *except* in one database where that column is `nvarchar(255)`.

So:

- 3 `NTEXT`
- 1 `nvarchar(255)`

My ETL takes data from these four tables and puts them into one table where the `Notes` column is of type `nvarchar(max)`.

I didn't realize that one column was `nvarchar(255)` until my ETL didn't work because all four tables are supposed to be identical in structure.

**Error:**

> [Source DB [25]] Error: There was an error with Source 
>   DB.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[Notes] on Source 
>   DB.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]. The column status returned was:
>   "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".

I'm guessing this is the issue since the error wasn't specific. How can I convert this column to `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: So, let me get this straight: this entire question could have been rewritten simply as "How can I convert an NTEXT column to NVARCHAR(MAX)?" right?

Comment: In your ole db source, could you write a select from the table and convert the column to NTEXT.  SELECT ..., Convert(ntext, Notes) as Notes?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz that worked! Thank you.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz why not writing this as an asnwer it is simple and useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the oledb source, write a select from the table and convert the column to NTEXT, i.e.

```
SELECT ..., Convert(ntext, Notes) as Notes
```